# Qt telnet client

Tags: c++, qt, telnet

I want to write a small and simple telnet client in C++ Qt. While searching internet I came across "QtTelnet" class. But it seems that this class has been dropped from latest Qt. Am I right? If yes, what is the best way to go about for writing a simple telnet client with c++ and Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has made a telnet widget on Google Code here: http://code.google.com/p/qtelnetperso

I browsed at the source and it doesn't use QtTelnet so you could either use the widget directly or learn from the source there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd better recommend the "qttelnet-2.1_1-opensource" from

http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/ftp.trolltech.com/pub/qt/solutions/lgpl/

It looks like the above widget was done from the QtTelnet-2.1.1 by removing some functionality.....